# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in jQuery definition?

Tags: jquery

I've never seen this before:

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#js-news').ticker(
      speed: 0.10,           // The speed of the reveal
      ajaxFeed: false,       // Populate jQuery News Ticker via a feed
      feedUrl: false,        // The URL of the feed
                       // MUST BE ON THE SAME DOMAIN AS THE TICKER
      feedType: 'xml',       // Currently only XML
      htmlFeed: true,        // Populate jQuery News Ticker via HTML
      debugMode: true,       // Show some helpful errors in the console or as alerts
                         // SHOULD BE SET TO FALSE FOR PRODUCTION SITES!
      controls: true,        // Whether or not to show the jQuery News Ticker controls
      titleText: 'Latest',   // To remove the title set this to an empty String
      displayType: 'reveal', // Animation type - current options are 'reveal' or 'fade'
      direction: 'ltr'       // Ticker direction - current options are 'ltr' or 'rtl'
      pauseOnItems: 2000,    // The pause on a news item before being replaced
      fadeInSpeed: 600,      // Speed of fade in animation
      fadeOutSpeed: 300      // Speed of fade out animation
    );
  });
</script>
```

That code is right before `</head>`. And `jQuery` is being included.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be missing `{}` in ticker:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#js-news').ticker({
          speed: 0.10,           // The speed of the reveal
          ajaxFeed: false,       // Populate jQuery News Ticker via a feed
          direction: 'ltr'
           ...........//--^-------missing ','
          fadeOutSpeed: 300      // Speed of fade out animation
     });
   });
</script>
```

Also as other answer suggested a missing `,` after `direction: 'ltr'`

Comment: +1, the first to identify the **main** issue. The others are also right about the missing comma, though.

Comment: Thanks guys! just noticed that first.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `,` after `direction: 'ltr'`